# Are blue/red cards blue and red, for preventing damage by protection circles?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If my opponent attacks with a [Niv-Mizzet](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=456216), can I prevent the damage with a [Circle of Protection: Blue](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCircle%5d%2b%5bof%5d%2b%5bProtection%5d%2b%5bBlue%5d)?

Comment: Remember that warning you got when you tried to post a question without enough text in it?  Adding a bunch of garbage to circumvent it does not go over well.  Please look through the [help] and review [ask] before posting here again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Niv-Mizzet is both blue *and* red, and both Circle of Protection: Blue and Circle of Protection: Red can prevent damage done by it.